# Creating Accordion layout items from datastore in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a Panel whose layout is accordin. I have a datastore which gets the data from server in json format and maps to a model. The data I get is a list of that model. Now in my view, I need to access the store and get all the records, and for each record I need to create a Panel and add it to the parent Panel.

My Store

```
Ext.define('NOS.store.ResultGroupsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires : ['NOS.model.ResultGroup'], 
    model: 'NOS.model.ResultGroup',
    fields:['groupName'],
    alias: 'widget.resultStore',
//  autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'showResult.nos',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

My View

```
Ext.require('Ext.panel.Panel');
Ext.define('NOS.view.ResultView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias:'widget.results',
    title: 'My title',
    layout:'accordion',
    items:null,
    initComponent : function() {
        console.log("reached in view initialise");
        results = Ext.create('NOS.store.ResultGroupsStore');
        results.load();
        results.each(function(aResultGroup, index) {
            console.log('Record ' + index);
        });
        console.log("End in view initialise");
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
});
```

But it never enters the loop above. I am sure the data is loaded properly to the store because when I use a grid.Panel and map the columns it renders the data.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store loading is asynchronous, when you you're iterating over the store, it hasn't loaded yet so the store is empty. You need to do it in the store callback.

```
Ext.require('Ext.panel.Panel');
Ext.define('NOS.view.ResultView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias:'widget.results',
    title: 'My title',
    layout:'accordion',
    items:null,
    initComponent : function() {
        var results = this.results = Ext.create('NOS.store.ResultGroupsStore');
        results.on('load', this.onStoreLoad, this, {
            single: true
        });
        results.load();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onStoreLoad: function() {
        this.store.each(function(rec){

        });
    }
});
```